# How do I get my server to boot normally again? Stuck at Grub command line

Tags: boot, server, grub2, 13.04

All of a sudden my Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring) server does not boot correctly anymore. It stops at a grub command line.

If I type `ls`, I get

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1) (fd0)
```

i can then `ls` each individual partition and the only one where it finds something is hd0,msdos1

I hooked up the hard disk to another PC and it seems to me all the data is still there!

How can I boot normally again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is problem with the grub menu.

Start by booting your ubuntu from a LiveCD or Live USB. You need to re-install grub on the server hard disk device. To know the device address, type in a terminal

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This will list the disks and their volumes in a list. Note the device where you need to install the grub. The size of thee device shall give you a hint. If /dev/sda is the device where grub needs to be installed, go to terminal and type

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Reboot your server and check if the problem is resolved.

**Update** : If the above fails, use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool to fix issues, or you can try

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda --force
```

Comment: thanks but that gives me the error: Path /boot/grub is not readable by GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible. Aborting.

Comment: I have added an update, try --force, else go for boot-repair

Comment: boot-repair did the trick

Answer (score 0):

i guess that happened after making a ubuntu kernel update , so you updated the kernel but not updated grub config , grub tries to boot the old kernel file but it's removed 
so let's boot manually from grub command line

first try ls (hd0,msdos1)/ and ... and find your /boot partition (or if all in one partition find your ubuntu partition)

when you find "/boot"(if you have separate partition for it) or "/" 
enter : `set root=(hd0,msdosX)`  this will set the root browsing directory for grub (replace X)

look for a file haveing "vmlinuz" in beginning of it's name 
and a file having "initrd" in beginnig of its name (they should be on the same folder in /boot or its subfolders, if there are multi files with that names select a pair that have the same version in their name (last is best ) )

now we suppose the files you've found are :`vmlinuz-4.19.0-kali4-amd64 & initrd.img-4.19.0-kali4-amd64`

in grub command line enter :
`linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-kali4-amd64
initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-kali4-amd64
boot`

congratulations you booted your ubuntu(or any other unix) successfully from grub command line manually and should see your OS starting up if you've done these step correctly